# How can I force a udeb to build with gzip?

Tags: debian, dpkg

The latest `dh_builddeb`, from Debian wheezy, builds udebs using *xz* compression, rather than the old *gzip* compression.  This is fine and dandy for wheezy systems, but I'm building udebs that are used to install squeeze systems.

Is there a way to force `dh_builddeb` to use gzip compression?  Here's what I've tried (in debian/rules):

```
dh_builddeb -- -Zgzip
```

However, this results in the following `dpkg-deb` command and error:

```
dpkg-deb: error: invalid compressor parameters: unknown compression strategy

Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;<br>
Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages.<br>
dh_builddeb: dpkg-deb -z1 -Zxz -Sextreme -Zgzip --build debian/dc-install-udeb ../dc-install-udeb_5.2.0~svn_all.udeb returned exit code 2
```

Is there a solution, short of using a squeeze machine to do my building?

Comment: Related meta question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183051/165502

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue was noticed with `btrfs-tools`.
This issue has been fixed [here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=673283)  Perhaps you can duplicate their fix for your package.

Comment: btrfs-tools has nothing to do with my problem. Although it appears they may have had the same problem.  I will try to investigate what they did and see if it solves my problem as well.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the bugtrack. I should have stated: "A similar bug was reported and fixed for `btrfs-tools`.